# If permissions all Unchecked does not update db

Tags: php, codeigniter

When the admin user unchecks all the user groups does not clear the permissions from db and throws error. If no permissions are selected and the form is submitted it should clear the permissions column belonging to that id. But does not for some reason?

What is best way to make it work?

```
Error Number: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE user_group_id = '10'' at line 4
UPDATE user_group SET name = 'Demonstration', permission = WHERE user_group_id = '10'
Filename: C:\Xampp\htdocs\codeigniter-project\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330
```

**User Group Model**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users_group_model extends CI_Model {

    public function addUserGroup($data) {
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . $this->db->dbprefix . "user_group SET name = " . $this->db->escape($data['name']) . ", permission = " . (isset($data['permission']) ? $this->db->escape(serialize($data['permission'])) : '') . " ");
    }

    public function editUserGroup($user_group_id, $data) {
        $this->db->query("UPDATE " . $this->db->dbprefix . "user_group SET 
            name = " . $this->db->escape($data['name']) . ", 
            permission = " . (isset($data['permission']) ? $this->db->escape(serialize($data['permission'])) : '') . " 
            WHERE 
            user_group_id = '" . (int)$user_group_id . "' 
        ");

    }

  public function getUserGroup($user_group_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " . $this->db->dbprefix . "user_group WHERE user_group_id = '" . (int)$user_group_id . "' ");

    $user_group = array(
        'name' => $query->row('name'),
        'permission' => unserialize($query->row('permission'))
    );

    return $user_group;
}
}
```

View Form

```
<?php
if (trim(!$user_group_id)) {
    echo form_open('admin/users_group/add', array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form', 'id' => "form-user-group"));
} else {
    echo form_open('admin/users_group/edit/' . $user_group_id, array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form','id' => "form-user-group"));
}
;?>

<div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-name"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_name; ?>" id="input-name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?php echo $entry_access; ?></label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="well well-sm" style="height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
        <?php foreach ($permissions as $permission) { ?>
            <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <?php if (in_array($permission, $access)) { ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="permission[access][]" value="<?php echo $permission; ?>" checked="checked" />
                <?php echo $permission; ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <input type="checkbox" name="permission[access][]" value="<?php echo $permission; ?>" />
                <?php echo $permission; ?>
            <?php } ?>
            </label>
        </div>
<?php } ?>
</div>
<a onclick="$(this).parent().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);"><?php echo $text_select_all; ?></a> / <a onclick="$(this).parent().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);"><?php echo $text_unselect_all; ?></a>
</div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?php echo $entry_modify; ?></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="well well-sm" style="height: 150px; overflow: auto;">
        <?php foreach ($permissions as $permission) { ?>
            <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
            <?php if (in_array($permission, $modify)) { ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="permission[modify][]" value="<?php echo $permission; ?>" checked="checked" />
                <?php echo $permission; ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
                <input type="checkbox" name="permission[modify][]" value="<?php echo $permission; ?>" />
                <?php echo $permission; ?>
            <?php } ?>
            </label>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<a onclick="$(this).parent().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', true);"><?php echo $text_select_all; ?></a> / 
<a onclick="$(this).parent().find(':checkbox').prop('checked', false);"><?php echo $text_unselect_all; ?></a></div>
</div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Users_group extends MX_Controller {
private $error = array();

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->lang->load('admin/user/users_groups', 'english');
    $this->load->model('admin/user/users_group_model');

    if(!$this->user->logged()) {
        redirect('admin');
    } elseif(!$this->user->hasPermissionAccess()) {
        redirect('admin/error');
    } else {
        return true;
    }
 }

public function index() {
    $this->document->setTitle($this->lang->line('heading_title'));
    $this->getList();
}


 public function add() {
    if ($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        $this->load->model('admin/user/users_group_model');

        $this->users_group_model->addUserGroup($this->request->post);

        redirect('admin/users_group');
    }

    $this->getForm();
}

public function edit() {
    $this->load->model('admin/user/users_group_model');

    if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validateForm()) {

        $user_group_id = $this->uri->segment(4);

        $this->users_group_model->editUserGroup($user_group_id, $this->request->post);

        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', $this->lang->line('text_success'));

        redirect('admin/users_group');

    }

protected function getForm() {
    $this->load->model('admin/user/users_group_model');
    $this->load->library('request');

    $data['heading_title'] = $this->lang->line('heading_title');

    $data['text_select_all'] = $this->lang->line('text_select_all');
    $data['text_unselect_all'] = $this->lang->line('text_unselect_all');

    $data['entry_name'] = $this->lang->line('entry_name');
    $data['entry_access'] = $this->lang->line('entry_access');
    $data['entry_modify'] = $this->lang->line('entry_modify');

    $data['button_save'] = $this->lang->line('button_save');
    $data['button_cancel'] = $this->lang->line('button_cancel');

    $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->lang->line('text_home'),
        'href' => site_url('admin/dashboard')
    );

    $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
        'text' => $this->lang->line('heading_title'),
        'href' => site_url('admin/users_group')
    );

    $data['cancel'] = site_url('admin/users_group');

    if (!empty($this->error['warning'])) {
        $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
    } else {
        $data['error_warning'] = '';
    }

    if (!empty($this->session->flashdata('success'))) {
        $data['success'] = $this->session->flashdata('success', $this->lang->line('text_success'));
    } else {
        $data['success'] = '';
    }

    $user_group_id = $this->uri->segment(4);
    $data['user_group_id'] = $user_group_id;

    if (isset($user_group_id)) {
        $data['action'] = site_url('user/users_group/add');
    } else {
        $data['action'] = site_url('admin/users_group/edit/' . $user_group_id);
    }

    if (!empty($user_group_id) && $this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
        $user_group_info = $this->users_group_model->getUserGroup($user_group_id);
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['name'])) {
        $data['name'] = $this->request->post['name'];
    } elseif (!empty($user_group_info)) {
        $data['name'] = $user_group_info['name'];
    } else {
        $data['name'] = '';
    }

    $ignore = array(
        'blank',
        'error',
        'register',
        'dashboard',
        'column_left',
        'menu',
        'startup',
        'login',
        'logout',
        'forgotten',
        'reset',
        'not_found',
        'permission',
        'footer',
        'header'
    );

    $data['permissions'] = array();

    $files = glob(APPPATH . 'modules/admin/' . 'controllers/*/*.php');

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $part = explode('/', dirname($file));

        $permission = basename($file, '.php');

        if (!in_array($permission, $ignore)) {
            $data['permissions'][] = $permission;
        }
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['permission']['access'])) {
        $data['access'] = $this->request->post['permission']['access'];
    } elseif (isset($user_group_info['permission']['access'])) {
        $data['access'] = $user_group_info['permission']['access'];
    } else {
        $data['access'] = array();
    }

    if (isset($this->request->post['permission']['modify'])) {
        $data['modify'] = $this->request->post['permission']['modify'];
    } elseif (isset($user_group_info['permission']['modify'])) {
        $data['modify'] = $user_group_info['permission']['modify'];
    } else {
        $data['modify'] = array();
    }

    $this->load->view('user/users_group_form', $data);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to the problem on the permissions when its not being set it breaks up the query. I suggest just the active record on CI on this one. Example:

```
public function editUserGroup($user_group_id, $data)
{
    $permission = (isset($data['permission']) ? serialize($data['permission']) : null);
    $update = array(
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'permission' => $permission,
    );
    $this->db->where('user_group_id', $user_group_id);
    $this->db->update($this->db->dbprefix . 'user_group', $update);
}
```

Or much cleaner using `->set()` (personal preference):

```
public function editUserGroup($user_group_id, $data)
{
    $permission = isset($data['permission']) ? serialize($data['permission']) : null;
    $this->db->set('permission', $permission);
    $this->db->set('name', $data['name']);
    $this->db->where('user_group_id', $user_group_id);
    $this->db->update($this->db->dbprefix . 'user_group', $update);
}
```

Comment: Now error 
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 256 bytes

Filename: user/users_group_model.php

Line Number: 38

Comment: @acoderslife why are you showing me this error? its not even included in this codes the you posted where is that located?

Comment: Because since added your code and refresh page it shows up now

Comment: @acoderslife so it means it updated? you have to walk me the thru this one if i'm going to be able to help

Comment: When user group form is submitted if access and or modify are selected it should update the db which it does. And what it should do if all permissions unchecked it should clear column permission column after form submitted. But now throws that error.

Comment: I added my user group model function to post that where that error belongs

Comment: @acoderslife try my revisions again, i think it messed up the serialization because when i used the active record it already escapes the strings, so it means it doubled the escape, kindly try the revision, (either one of those, but i like the second one better)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63263/discussion-between-acoderslife-and-ghost).